# Angular 5 ng-option readonly item

Tags: angular, readonly, ng-options, angular-ngselect

First of all, excuse me for my bad English. I'm writing applications on ASP.NET Core 2 WebApi and Angular with NG-ZORRO.

In general, I have a problem with drop-down lists. According to the terms of reference, the administrator can mark one of the items of the directory as hidden and at the same time it should not be available for selection or should not be communicated to the client's side. But in the previously created application cards, the values should be displayed even if they were marked as cached in the database. Here is such a cool business analyst in our company.

Accordingly, I have a model directory in SQL (id, name, isDeleted). When a user opens an application card, he receives all the previously-filled IDs.

One of them. For the convenience of leaving only one controller:

```
<div nz-form-control nz-col [nzLg]="18" 
                         [nzValidateStatus]="typeServices">
                        <nz-select formControlName="typeServices" 
                                   [nzPlaceHolder]="'Выберите вид услуги'" 
                                   [nzNotFoundContent]="'Услуга не найдена'" 
                                   nzShowSearch>
                            <nz-option *ngFor="let option of typeServicesList"
                                       [nzLabel]="option.name"
                                       [nzValue]="option.id">
                            </nz-option>
                        </nz-select>
                        <div nz-form-explain *ngIf="(typeServices.dirty || typeServices.touched)
                             && typeServices.errors?.required">
                             Пожалуйста, введите вид услуги!
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

My component:

```
export class CardDetailsInfoComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
private ngUnsubscribe: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

form: FormGroup;
typeServicesList = [];

get typeServices() { return this.form.controls.typeServices; }

constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private tabDetailsStore: TabDetailsStore,
    private readonly httpCardService: ApplicationCardHttpService,
    private cardService: ApplicationCardService,
    private realizationRatingBackendService: RealizationRatingBackendService) {        

    this.cardService.cardOnChange
        .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
        .subscribe(card => {               

        this.typeServicesList = this.cardService.cardReferences.servicetypes;

        this.typeServices.setValue(card.serviceTypeId);                               

    });

    this.cardService.onSaved()
        .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
        .subscribe(() => {                
            if (this.tabDetailsStore.activeTab.type === TabDetailsType.CommonInfo) {                    
                if (this.form.valid) {
                    this.cardService.setServiceTypeId(this.typeServices.value);
                    this.save();
                } else {
                    this.cardService.saveCompleted(SaveStatus.Undefined);
                }
            }
        });
}

private save() {
    return this.httpCardService.saveMainData(this.cardService.card)
        .subscribe(() => {
            this.cardService.saveCompleted(SaveStatus.Successful);
        }, (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            this.cardService.saveCompleted(SaveStatus.Error);
            console.log(err);
        });
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
        typeServices: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required]), null]
    });  
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
    this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
}
```

I get the model of the card from the server in which the id of the desired item of the directory is. I substitute this value in the form of the counterlighter and the angular substitutes the name.
The library NG-ZORRO has options [nzDeseble] but that's not exactly what I need.

How to make it so that the value hidden by the administrator in the drop-down list is unavailable for selection, but if the value is stored in the model, it is displayed in the control. I guess that it needs to be somehow substituted in form.value but such a decision will entail great changes in architecture. What proposals do you have?